# symfony2 check on kernelRequest if the request is an assetic

Tags: symfony, events, request

I need to know on the onKernelRequest eventListener, if the request is an assetic route.

How can i do that? I hot this listener:

```
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{

    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {      
        return;
    }

    // Here i need check if the request owns to an assetic

    if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) 
    {
        // do something...
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: what does your template look like?

Comment: This is not relevant :/

Comment: While this may be possible in dev environment, when assetic dumps assets, static files are written to the web root. The web server will serve these directly, so there is no way to listen to these requests in Symfony.

Comment: @phpprogrammer are you sure? files can be included in several ways with assetic.

Comment: Ok, then what you need to answer me correctly?

Comment: As a workaround you can dump your asset files as in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-prod-environment, and serve them statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that routes generated by assetic always contain the string `'_assetic_'` according to [AsseticLoader](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/blob/master/Routing/AsseticLoader.php) line 116. So you should check that the matched route doesn't contain that string. e.g:

```
// in your listener:
// return from the listener if this as an assetic route
if ( strpos($event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route'), 'assetic') !== false)
  return;
```

Comment: Thats it, i do that on twig but doesn't know to do in PHP!

Thanks a lot!